# If hassClass then addClass to parent not working?

Tags: jquery

Why is this not adding a class to :

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
   <li id="menu-item-18" class="current-menu-item page_item current_page_item">
      <a href="#">Sitename</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
if ($('.sub-menu li').hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Same result with:

```
if ($('li').hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` doesn't refer to the element that you located in the `if` statement.

You would loop through the elements and check each one:

```
$('.sub-menu li').each(function(i, el){
  if ($(el).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
    $(el).parent().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

However, in this case you can just select the matching elements, get each parent element and add the class to all of them:

```
$('.sub-menu li.current-menu-item').parent().addClass('active');
```